# Use of tags: [congress], [senate], and [house-of-representatives], for US questions

Tags: discussion, tags

1. There are [78 questions tagged](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bhouse-of-representatives%5D+or+%5Bsenate%5D+%5Bcongress%5D+is%3Aq) with [house-of-representatives](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-of-representatives) or [senate](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senate) which are also tagged [congress](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congress).
2. There are [26 questions tagged](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-of-representatives+senate) with [house-of-representatives](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-of-representatives) and [senate](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senate). [Five of those questions are also tagged](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-of-representatives+senate+congress) [congress](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congress).
3. Therefore, 99 questions may be over-tagged depending on the usefulness of the tags for the question and whether the question relates to the US.
4. For comparison, there are [274 questions tagged](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bhouse-of-representative%5D+or+%5Bsenate%5D+-%5Bcongress%5D+is%3Aq) with [house-of-representatives](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-of-representatives) or [senate](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senate) which are not tagged [congress](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congress). Not all of those are for the US.

Should the [congress] tag be omitted when referring specifically to the [house-of-representatives] or the [senate]?

When referring to both the [house-of-representatives] and the [senate], should only the [congress] tag be used?

---

There being only 5 tags available for a question, freeing a tag would allow adding other tags, particularly, the [united-states] tag for some questions at the 5 tag limit.

Comment: Why would you suggest that both tags not be used?

Comment: @JoeW - There are only 5 tags available. I've noticed a "disturbing" tendency for some to drop the [united-states] tag when asking questions related to the US. Freeing a tag would allow adding the [united-states] tag.

Comment: Wouldn't that be good information to include in the question? I wasn't gathering that some tags are getting dropped because of the 5 tag limit based on what you asked.

Comment: @JoeW - Of the 3 tags noted, there are over 30 questions that do not have the [united-states] tag. Only a few are at the 5 tag limit. There are literally a few hundred questions related to the US that are missing the [united-states] tag. Some of those are also at the 5 tag limit; but, for this question, I wanted to limit the consideration to the use of those tags. The question of the missing tag for US questions is a topic for another day.

Comment: I understand that now, but can't you edit that into the question so that it is more clear why this is an issue?

Comment: Are there experts in "senates"? Are there people that follow only questions about senates or upper houses but not HoRs or lower houses? It seems like a bit of an over-specification especially when, as you point out, they would always be tagged with a country and a legislature tag (I imagine you could have the same issue with UK/parliament/HoL). If there's a question about the systems *generally* they could be tagged "bicameralism" or maybe just "congress" vs. "parliament"?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- *Are there people that follow only questions about senates or upper houses but not HoRs or lower houses?* Watchers: Congress - 3, Senate - 2, House... - 0, Parliament - 11. The question is about using more tags than necessary and leaving out relevant, potentially useful, tags. A similar case occurs with using a party tag and the [parties] tag (24 questions).

Comment: Then yes - it does seem unnecessary to tag questions with both a legislature and a house tag.

Answer (score 2):

One example of a fully loaded tag set is a question about the House and Senate rules regarding the impeachment of a US president that could use eight tags. These would include:

- [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states)
- [house-rules](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-rules) and [senate-rules](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senate-rules)
- [impeachment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/impeachment)
- [president](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/president)
- [house-of-representatives](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-of-representatives), [senate](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senate) and [congress](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congress)

Note that having used five relevant tags, there is no room for the last set of tags. The absence of those tags does not prevent such a question from being found, since a search using [impeachment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/impeachment), [president](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/president), [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) will locate the question.

---

There are <strike>31</strike> [30 questions tagged](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bhouse-rules%5d%20or%20%5bsenate-rules%5d%20is%3aq%20-%5bhouse-of-representatives%5d%20-%5bsenate%5d%20-%5bcongress%5d%20-%5baustralia%5d%20-%5bvoting-systems%5d) [house-rules](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-rules) or [senate-rules](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senate-rules) that do not include any of [house-of-representatives](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-of-representatives), [senate](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senate) or [congress](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congress). (Two tags were also excluded to remove questions unrelated to the US.)

I did tag (and other) edits on six questions. Four to add relevant tags, one with no effect on tags, and one to remove a tag that reduced the count. In each case and IMO, the questions are well-tagged without tags for the House, Senate or Congress. (Though some other tags are questionable and I ignored minor edits.)

- [12 questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-rules+house-of-representatives) use both [house-rules](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-rules) and [house-of-representatives](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-of-representatives)
- [71 questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsenate-rules%5D+%5Bsenate%5D+-%5Bcanada%5D+is%3Aq) use both [senate-rules](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senate-rules) and [senate](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senate) (Two are missing [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states).)
- [29 questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bhouse-of-representatives%5D+%5Bcongress%5D+is%3Aq+-%5Bsenate%5D) use both [house-of-representatives](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-of-representatives) and [congress](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congress) and not [senate](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senate)
- [44 questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5bsenate%5d%20%5bcongress%5d%20is%3aq%20-%5bhouse-of-representatives%5d) use both [senate](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senate) and [congress](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congress) and not [house-of-representatives](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-of-representatives) (Five are missing [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states).)

Seven of the above questions are missing [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states). None of those had five tags.

While I did not review those 156 questions, some containing seemingly redundant tags did reach the five tag limit.

The is no [search type](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search) for the number of tags. Trying to find a good case for not having redundant tags would require a scattershot approach; nonetheless keeping redundancy to a minimum may be beneficial.

---

I have posted a question: [How can I limit search results to questions with exactly five tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369166/824951), on Meta StackExchange to see it there is a way to do this.